# Encapsulate std::map to allow iterating, but no direct key access?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, encapsulation

Is there a way to encapsulate `std::map` within a user-defined class, allowing iteration, but not allowing direct access to the key?

I would like to manipulate the key upon insertion and I want to force all access to elements through a user-defined method (as the key will need to be modified).

I think the problem is allowing iterating over the map, whilst preventing the user from accessing the key via the iterator.

Comment: Wrap the iterator?

Comment: You can make your own iterator that wraps over the actual map iterator, but dereferences to only the value. Boost has transforming iterators for this, but it is trivial to write your own.

Comment: If you are manipulating the key on insertion, how will the user of the map know they have got a particular element if the key (on iteration) is not the value they expect?

Comment: What's the problem with exposing transformed keys?

Answer (score 0):

Do not expose iterators. Expose a `for_each` function that passes each element to the user-provided (lambda) function.

Alternatively, use a [transform iterator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/iterator/doc/html/iterator/specialized/transform.html).

Comment: Sounds highly inefficient and less flexible. Unless the compiler can optimize away lambda expressions somehow.

Comment: @riv I see no reason for the inefficiency - the compiler can inline. Try compiling your code with optimisations enabled.

Comment: Lambdas aren't free, especially when wrapped in `std::function`, and are a nightmare to debug (though newer VS versions can skip over STL code). Iterator is much better, and lets you use range-based for.

Comment: @riv _Lambdas aren't free_ - it depends. Quit making baseless claims.

Comment: @riv You are conflating two things together. Yes, when `std::function` wraps a lambda, there is a cost of indirect call. However, it was not suggested in the answer to do this. And when lambdas are passed as templated callbacks, they are, in fact, highly inlineable and come as close to 'free' as it gets. On the other hand, obviously, sometimes explicit loop is more expressive, than for_each call.

Comment: You're right, they do seem to have the same performance as iterator version, but the expressiveness point still stands.