# Prevent direct access to std::map keys

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, iterator

I would like to wrap a `std::map` so the client is unaware that I am storing their positive integer keys actually as negative integers. I need to allow iterating over the class and accessing the elements.

I thought-up this class:

```
template<class K, class V>
class Container
{
public:

    Container(){}

    void insert(const K& key, const V& value)
    {
        _map[key] = value;
    }

    bool getFirstElement(K& key, V& value)
    {
        if (false == _map.empty())
        {
            _iter = _map.begin();
            value = _iter->second;
            key = std::abs(_iter->first);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool getNextElement(K& key, V& value)
    {
        ++_iter;
        if (_iter != _map.end())
        {
            key = std::abs(_iter->first);  // I modify the key
            value = _iter->second;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

private:
    typename std::map<K, V>::iterator _iter; // Caches client's position whilst iterating
    std::map<K, V> _map;
};
```

The usage would be:

```
int main()
{
    Container<int, int> o;

    o.insert(-1, 100);
    o.insert(-2, 200);
    o.insert(-3, 300);

    int key;
    int value;
    o.getFirstElement(key, value);

    std::cout << "key: " << key << " val: " << value << std::endl;

    while (o.getNextElement(key, value))
    {
        std::cout << "key: " << key << " val: " << value << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However, I don't like having two methods to iterate, first `getFirstElement()` outside of the loop and **then** `getNextElement()` within the loop.

Is there a way to achieve this so the client can write neater code?

Comment: `getFirstElement` is declared to return a `bool`, but doesn't contain a `return` statement. Any call to it would exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: You can implement a custom iterator to go with your custom container.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Sorry I changed that in my IDE after I wrote the question. Updated now.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, could you possibly provide an example?

Comment: [Let me Google it for you](https://www.google.com/search?q=a+custom+iterator+C%2B%2B)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encapsulate std::map to allow iterating, but no direct key access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51862149/encapsulate-stdmap-to-allow-iterating-but-no-direct-key-access)

Comment: Your `abs` call is buggy, and could invoke undefined behavior for MIN_INT.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler isn't that just a property of std::abs()?

Comment: @user997112 it is a property of `int`, which affects `std::abs()`. It is not guaranteed that `-MIN_INT` is undefined, and depends on how negatives are represented. On intel architecture, negative integers are represented by two's complement, so they have this property. On a system with one's complement, or with sign-value, this problem does not exist. Anyway, using std::abs on an unrestricted integer is calling for trouble, and has a risk of undefined behavior. Read cppreference

Answer (score 0):

```
do 
{
    std::cout << "key: " << key << " val: " << value << std::endl;
}while (o.getNextElement(key, value));
```

So all operations are within the loop like this.

Comment: Okay, that's one better than mine, but it still requires the user to call getFirstElement() before getNextElement()

Comment: What dose it mean by "still requires the user to call getFirst..."?

Comment: Copy and paste my code in an IDE, try your solution and you'll understand.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this:

```
if( false == o.empty() )
{
    do 
    {
        std::cout << "key: " << key << " val: " << value << std::endl;
    }while (o.getNextElement(key, value));
}
```

To judge whether it is 'null', before you get elements.